# how to embed android emulator in HTML page

Tags: java, android, html

i am working on a project that enables a user to have a demo of an application that he is about to download..
something similar to https://www.manymo.com ; but i am struck on how to embed the emulator in the webpage. 
Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the manymo link. Didn't know that such a thing existed.

Comment: @greenapps-can you help in this ??

Comment: No, no, ... Sorry.. No idea...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a way on how to approach

Create android emulator and install VNC server 
then use a web based vnc client and embeded it in your server .(most solutions need activex/java enabled browsers).

webased VNC clients to look out for 
https://novnc.com/info.html

embedding instructions

https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/blob/master/docs/EMBEDDING.md

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be

- Create a minimal android emulator image and install the app
- Start a server that

  - starts the android emulator
  - has Chrome remote desktop
  - the size of the desktop is exactly the size of the emulator
- In the browser, offer a Chrome remote view that connects to the server