# Run android emulator on remote ssh based linux machine and display it on local browser

Tags: android, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine, remote-debugging

I have recently been playing around with code-server, which is a Visual Studio Code IDE that can be ran on the remote machine and accessed through the browser. For that I made a google vm instance of Ubuntu LTS 16.04, and I was successfull to launch it and install the Flutter and Dart sdks. Because of the flutter_web and flutter itself still being unable to unify in one codebase, I ran into a lot of incompatibilities which made it impossible to debug my application as a web-site.

Now I want to launch the android emulator instead, because I would be able to test and debug the apps, but I didn't find any source of information on how to install it and display it remotely, for example, in local browser.

Is it practically possible? And if it is, please tell me how. Because me being able to develop flutter apps on iPad would be really cool.

Comment: See: [How to embed android emulator in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24287522/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this out of our scope as is not related to the Google Compute Engine product, anyway I would give my best effort to help you:

Google Marketplace has an awesome product called Genymotion [1] which is an Android Emulator. I tried and it's one click deploy, very useful.

---

[1] https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/partners/genymotion-public-project

Comment: It works but it's really expensive dude. I can run full Graphical OS with vsCode and emulators instead for the prices they offer

Answer (score -1):

Cuttlefish might be your best bet; I believe it's specifically designed for your use case, and you can interact with the device via the web.

Here is some more information from the web site:

> You can interact with Cuttlefish just like you would with any other Android device that you might use for debugging. It will register itself as a normal device via adb and you can interact with it like a physical device via remote desktop. The use cases are broad and can span application testing, custom system build testing and more.

> Because Cuttlefish strives for full framework fidelity, it can be used for functional testing of your framework and/or applications where there are no physical hardware dependencies that are impossible to emulate.

Since there is way too much detail as it relates to setup and related, this information is better presented at the source, https://source.android.com/docs/devices/cuttlefish.